# What's the difference between shrinking files or database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, shrink

I need more space in my development environment and need to shrink my database (or files) in SQL Server. Should I chose "shrink files" or "shrink database" to free most disk space?

[image: Shrink options in SQL Server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database contains more than one data file, with the "Shrink Files" options you can choose which file you want to shrink; "Shrink Database" will shrink all of them.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Does this inclide LOG-files?

Comment: Yes, but they will only be shrunk if there are inactive logs on them, i.e. if the DB is set to simple recovery model or if a transaction log backup has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

Shrink: Basically, if used, this option is to compress your database size or used unusable space.

If you Shrink the database, then all your database will have more space.

If you are Shrink files, then more file space will be available.